# Swimming long distances self sufficient

Tags: equipment, swimming, open-water

I intend to swim long distances, over 5 km, in open waters. I won't do it in shark infested water or anything alike, but there are still a lot of dangers, like jellyfishes.

I also want to do it self sufficient.

I suspect that I would need at least an auto inflating vest. But what should I look for when choosing one? If I would need to carry food and water how can I do it? Is there something like a floating bag that I can easily attach to myself?

Related to safety again, is there something like a radio buoy to emit a signal in case of emergency?

Any other tips if someone already did this?

Comment: This is an important object you can use for your training http://swimsafetydevice.com/ but I do not swim in open water so I am not able to give a complete reply on it

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a really good device. I'm thinking of buying one and that kind of things is what I'm looking for. There is still the question of the flotation vest.

Comment: Maybe it is better to search or ask in [Physical Fitness_swim_tag section](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swimming) / [Physical Fitness_seaswim_tag section](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-swimming)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm [swimsafety](http://swimsafetydevice.com/) and I add a picture to understand better [image: swimsafety]

I discover a new item that can help in open water swimming:
[lifebelt](http://www.theswimit.com/) [image: lifebelt_closed] [image: lifebelt_opening]

Are all commercial links but I cannot explain it exactly in a different way